# How can I access a data submitted in a form which is saved as another file with nodejs without using any framework

Tags: html, node.js, forms, post

I am new to Node.JS and I am trying to display the submitted data in a form which is stored as an html file using Node.JS. How can I do that?
I don't want to use any framework as I want to make my base stronger.

Here is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Sample Form with Node.JS and MongoDB</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script src="sample.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" action="incoming" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Sample Form</legend>
                <p><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter your Name"></p>
                <p><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your Email"></p>
                <p><input type="submit" name="submit"></p>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is my sample.js

```
var http=require('http');
var qs=require('querystring');
var fs=require('fs')
var port=8000;
http.createServer(function(req,res){
    if(req.method==="GET"){
        fs.readFile('index.html',function(err,data){
            res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'text/html'});
            res.write(data);
            res.end();
        });
    }
    else if(req.method==='POST'){
        if(req.url==='/incoming'){
            var reqbody='';
            req.on('data',function(data){
                reqbody+=data;
            });
            req.on('end',function (){
                var formdata=qs.parse(reqbody);
                res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'text/html'});
                res.write('<fieldset><legend>Form Inputs</legend>');
                res.write('Name: '+formdata.name);
                res.write('Email: '+formdata.email);
                res.end('</fieldset></body></html>');
            });
        }
    }
}).listen(port);
```

Your help would be appreciated. Thank You in advance.

**UPDATE**

Removing the enctype somehow worked and now it's working just fine. Thanks

Comment: Excuse me, what do you get now after `POST` on `/incoming`?

Comment: @Ingaz
Name: undefined
E-Mail: undefined

Comment: @Ingaz removing the enctype did the magic.

Comment: are you trying to start a server on client side ?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the enctype from index.html, I don't know why it worked but when I was fiddling with my code to make it work removing the enctype did the trick